# how to to make responsive bootstrap design with this css file

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, responsive-design

need to make responsive design with following css file with bootstrap. this I am using following codes to create My menu bar I need make responsive design It.

this is My tutorial link
https://codepen.io/CreativeJuiz/pen/oCBxz

```
[1]: http://codepen.io/CreativeJuiz/pen/oCBxz
```

Comment: It's a codepen error page. Means you want to design page like this with responsiveness?

Comment: No please see My edited link

Comment: I guess In a way to achieve responsive with this css you have to apply proper col-* classes of bootstrap as per your needs

Comment: did you mean may I change this In html file?

Comment: it is very unclear what you are asking. Please rethink your questions. To learn bootstrap this is not the place to be. Read the tutorials which you easily find on the web

Answer (score -2):

```js
var theToggle = document.getElementById('toggle');

// based on Todd Motto functions
// https://toddmotto.com/labs/reusable-js/

// hasClass
function hasClass(elem, className) {
 return new RegExp(' ' + className + ' ').test(' ' + elem.className + ' ');
}
// addClass
function addClass(elem, className) {
    if (!hasClass(elem, className)) {
     elem.className += ' ' + className;
    }
}
// removeClass
function removeClass(elem, className) {
 var newClass = ' ' + elem.className.replace( /[\t\r\n]/g, ' ') + ' ';
 if (hasClass(elem, className)) {
        while (newClass.indexOf(' ' + className + ' ') >= 0 ) {
            newClass = newClass.replace(' ' + className + ' ', ' ');
        }
        elem.className = newClass.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
    }
}
// toggleClass
function toggleClass(elem, className) {
 var newClass = ' ' + elem.className.replace( /[\t\r\n]/g, " " ) + ' ';
    if (hasClass(elem, className)) {
        while (newClass.indexOf(" " + className + " ") >= 0 ) {
            newClass = newClass.replace( " " + className + " " , " " );
        }
        elem.className = newClass.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
    } else {
        elem.className += ' ' + className;
    }
}

theToggle.onclick = function() {
   toggleClass(this, 'on');
   return false;
}
```

```css
/* Important styles */
#toggle {
  display: block;
  width: 28px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 30px auto 10px;
}

#toggle span:after,
#toggle span:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: -9px;
}
#toggle span:after{
  top: 9px;
}
#toggle span {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

#toggle span,
#toggle span:after,
#toggle span:before {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #888;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

/* on activation */
#toggle.on span {
  background-color: transparent;
}
#toggle.on span:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(5px, 5px);
}
#toggle.on span:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(7px, -8px);
}
#toggle.on + #menu {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

/* menu appearance*/
#menu {
  position: relative;
  color: #999;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: auto;
  font-family: "Segoe UI", Candara, "Bitstream Vera Sans", "DejaVu Sans", "Bitstream Vera Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, "Verdana Ref", sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
  /* just for this demo */
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: opacity .4s;
}
#menu:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  left: 95px;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  border-left: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right: 15px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid white;
}
ul, li, li a {
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
li a {
  padding: 5px;
  color: #888;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all .2s;
}
li a:hover,
li a:focus {
  background: #1ABC9C;
  color: #fff;
}


/* demo styles */
body { margin-top: 3em; background: #eee; color: #555; font-family: "Open Sans", "Segoe UI", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; }
p, p a { font-size: 12px;text-align: center; color: #888; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1,shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    
    <title>TEST</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>

<body>
    <a href="#menu" id="toggle"><span></span></a>
    <div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: explaining a bit, what's wrong with previous code and what have you done would be helpful

Comment: what should I change newly @Swadesh Dash

Comment: I mean may I only change html file .col tags not change any thing in css file @ParthGoswami

Comment: No i was suggesting to apply col- classes to your html file.

Comment: In HTML use only bootstrap class. nothing is required